# How to improve performance of application for inserting list in elasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, performance-testing

I have 2000 entries in my List and trying to insert this list into elasticsearch by API which is nothing but a bulk request.
Please find below code for the same.

```
     for(Car car : carList){
            elasticSearchService.addOrganization(car,"Car");
        }

Code for ElasticSearch Service

        @Autowired
        private Client esClient;

        private void addOrganization(Object object, String modelName){
                Gson gson  = new Gson();
                final String json = gson.toJson(object);
                esClient.prepareIndex("ElasticSearchIndex",modelName).setSource(json).execute().actionGet();
        }

I have made following entry in elasticsearch.yml file
threadpool:
    index:
        size: 250
        queue_size: 1000
```

As we are monitoring performance of the application through JMeter, we found that our application generates 2000 HTTP requests to connect and put data in elasticsearch 
which takes around 10 seconds for this task.Can we make connectionpool in esClient or is there any way to do configuration at elasticsearch server so that performance of the application can be improved and
response time will be reduced upto 3 seconds?

Comment: Did you try indexing? did you distribute the data using shard (whole data is distributed for faster access)? did you provide multiple Nodes (of same data - redundancy & faster access). It seems like tuning question. you have to ask this question to your performance engineer.

Comment: We tried increasing the threadpool as mentioned above but no improvement in the performance and even increasing/decreasing the shards yield no good results

Comment: I would suggest you put the load in steps like 100, 200, 300, 400...900, 1000....2000 etc (in a single test, if you want,  use Stepping ThreadGroup, https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/). so, you will have a clear idea at what load, the response times are crossing the threshold values (like 3 seconds as u mentioned). based on that you can take the decision to whether scale in/out the infrastructure or re-look at the existing deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking of bulk requests but not using them:

Change your code to:

```
elasticSearchService.addOrganizations(carList,"Car");
```

And your ElasticSearch Service code to:

```
@Autowired
private Client esClient;

private void addOrganizations(List<Object> objects, String modelName){
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    objects.forEach(object -> {
        Gson gson  = new Gson();
        final String json = gson.toJson(object);
        bulkRequest.add(esClient.prepareIndex("ElasticSearchIndex",modelName).setSource(json));
    });
    bulkRequest.get();
}
```

See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html) to have more information.

Comment: Thanks Pandawan. This code worked for my application.